# C++ - Failed loading a data file !

Tags: c++, file, ifstream

I have a simple data file that I want to load, in a C++ program. For weird reasons, it doesn't work:

- I tried it on Windows assuming the file was in the same directory: *failed*.
- I tried it on Windows by moving the file in C:\ directory: *worked*.
- I tried it on Linux putting the file in the same directory: *failed*.

The snippet:

```
void World::loadMap(string inFileName) {
  ifstream file(inFileName.c_str(), ios::in);
  if (file) {
  }
  else 
  {
    cout<<"Error when loading the file \n";
    exit(-1);
  }
}
```

I call the loadMap method like this:

```
World::Instance()->loadMap("Map.dat");
```

(World is a singleton class).

**How can I find the exact error, by using try-catch or anything else?**

Comment: I guess, to be portable, you'll need to use full path.

Comment: Using `"./filename"` (the `./` is assumed and not even required) is portable across Windows and Linux, the problem could be that the CWD isn't what he thinks it is, though.

Comment: can you try to write a simple file operation program and see if things work. just #include <fstream> using namespace std; int main () { ifstream fin ("map.dat"); if (fin.EOF()) return 1; else { fin.close(); return 0;}}

Comment: Bo Tian: it's eof (lowercase) and you should only use it to test a previous stream operation: it does not tell you if the *next* input would fail due to EOF.

Comment: Thanks Roger !! It solved my problem ! And thanks++ for the edit !
Can you please move your answer to "Answer", so I can set is as best answer ?

Comment: Amokrane: I'm not sure what solution I provided (I was really replying to Drakosha's comment).  If you're sure none of the current answers work, this sounds like it would be appropriate for you to post an answer to your own question.  (However, Neil's answer does address a big part of your question, and recognized its significance even before my formatting edit---you may want to accept his answer.)

Comment: Roger, this one helped me solving the problem: Using "./filename" (the ./ is assumed and not even required) is portable across Windows and Linux, the problem could be that the CWD isn't what he thinks it is, though.

I did : World::Instance()->loadMap("./Map.dat"); and now it's working !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the working directory.

When you specify a relative path for a file it uses the working directory (which may not be the same as the directory where you application is stored on the file system).

- Thus you either need to use an absolute path.
- Or you need to find the current working directory and specify the file relative to that.
- Or change the current working directory.

Answer (score 2):

By default, a file failing to open (or any other I/O operation) does not raise an exception. You can change this behaviour, but the standard still provides no means of extracting from an exception the exact reason for failure.

Comment: Prasoon: in the future, probably a good idea to wait until the post is 5 mintues old before editing for that---let the author have a window to find those errors himself, and 5 mins corresponds to what SO recognizes as "the same edit".

Comment: @Roger I don't mind people fixing my typos - I'm a pretty crap typist. I agree in general with you, though.

Answer (score 1):

Linux filenames are case-sensitive.
Is your file actually named `map.dat`?

Also, did you try putting the file in the current directory?

Comment: The file  is Map.dat. And yes it's in the current directory !

Answer (score 1):

Roger Pate's comment:

> Using `"./filename"` (the `./` is assumed and not even required) is portable across Windows and Linux, the problem could be that the CWD isn't what he thinks it is, though.